# Applescript - save argument to text file

Tags: applescript

I need to write a simple applescript that will be opened with an argument. That argument will be a file path. I need it to save this file path to a text file. I want to avoid using shell script.

I'm finding this surprisingly difficult, despite having done it in .sh and .bat already

Thanks very much!

Adam

//// the current code which is not working is below. the code begins with "on run" and ends with "end run" but for some reason this isn't being highlighted as code

---

```
on run argv
    set this_PATH to (POSIX file argv)

    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        make new document
        set text of document 1 to this_PATH as text
        save document 1 in "/Users/adamparkinson/Desktop/date.txt"
    end tell
end run
```

---

Comment: You should add the (non-working) code you've tried, so the errors/problems can be pointed out :-)

Comment: thanks! good point! I've tried about 40 things so I've just added the latest :)

Comment: CTRL-Click into a script to see code snippets. under "Error Handler", "Write Errors to log" it shows how to write something to a text file (without TextEdit).

Answer (score 0):

I made this work:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
            make new document
            tell document 1
                set its text to (item 1 of argv as text)
                save in posix file (item 1 of argv as text ) 
            end tell
        end tell
end run
```

I called it like this:

`./SavePath.sh /Users/Me/Desktop/junk/Newstuff.txt` (Of course I used `chmod u+x SavePath.sh` to make it executable.)
If this works for you, then please check of my answer as answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

with applescript it is very easy to create application Drag and Drop without any script shell below a version Drag and Drop of your script

```
 on open draggedItems
    set this_PATH to quoted form of POSIX path of draggedItems
    repeat with currentItem in draggedItems
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set doc to open POSIX file "/Users/adamparkinson/Desktop/date.txt"
    make new word at end of text of doc with data (this_PATH as text) & return
end tell        
    end repeat
end open
```